# What are the semi-simple groups and algebras of rank $4$ or less?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I was able to find the following groups which are claimed to be semi-simple:

- Lorentz group is $SO(3,1)$, or is it $SO^+(3,1)$
- $SU(3)$ is semi-simple
- $SU(2)$ is semi-simple
- $U(1) \times SU(2) \times SU(3)$ is semi-simple
- Toral subalgebra

It seems move of the groups of interest to physics are semi-simples.

What other groups have I missed (I am only interested in less than $4$ dimensions). I am also surely confusing a semi-simple group vs algebra.

Am I correct to think that all semi-simple algebras are subgroups of the Toral algebra?

Comment: Some of the dimensions on your list exceed 4

Comment: Do you mean rank instead of dimension? All these group except $SU(2)$ have dimension above $4$.

Comment: You second question is also very confusing. There isn't a singular toral algebra. A toral algebra of a lie algebra is  an abelian algebra. It is not a group. You can have a toral group, which is just a torus. In both cases, semi-simple algebras/groups will not embed into them.

Comment: @max Yes I did meant rank.

Comment: You can look at the table at bottom of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group for a list of low dimensional simple groups. To obtain semi-simple groups, just take products to obtain all of them (atleast up to finite subgroups)

Comment: I once asked physicists why so many Lie groups in physics are semisimple, esp. in QFT. They had a good answer: It is because physics requires measurements, angles, and lengths. These can only be defined by semisimple Lie algebras. Exceptions are the Heisenberg groups and the Poincaré group, which are as far as I know no gauge groups.

Comment: @max Thank you for the list of simple groups, but I am confused. On the second line, it states SU(2) as an element of the list. I thought SU(2) was semi-simple and not simple.

Comment: @anon21 $SU(2)$ is simple and semi-simple. Semi-simple is less restrictive than simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned above, to answer your question, atleast for semi-simple algebras, it is sufficient to list all simple algebras.

To begin, I will first list the complex simple algebras of rank less than 4:
$\mathfrak{sl_{n+1}}(\mathbb{C})$,$\mathfrak{sp_{2n}}(\mathbb{C})$ for $1\le n\le 4$,
$\mathfrak{so_{n}}(\mathbb{C})$ for $3\le n\le 9$, $\mathfrak{g_2},\mathfrak{f_4}$

I will omit the $\mathbb{C}$ for this paragraph for simplicity. This list contain multiple redundancies, for example $\mathfrak{sl_2}=\mathfrak{sp_{2}}=\mathfrak{so_{3}}$. A minimal list could be $\mathfrak{sl_2},\mathfrak{sl_3},\mathfrak{sl_4},\mathfrak{sl_5},\mathfrak{so_5},\mathfrak{so_7},\mathfrak{sp_{4}},\mathfrak{sp_{6}},\mathfrak{sp_{8}},\mathfrak{so_8},\mathfrak{g_2},\mathfrak{f_2},$ are multiple ways to do so.

Now, each simple real Lie algebra complexifies to a simple complex Lie algebra. I will list all simple real Lie algebras that complexify to the members of the above list.

The algebras $\mathfrak{su}_{p,q}$ for $p+q=n$, $\frak{sl}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ complexify to $\mathfrak{sl}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, and the algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_{n}(\mathbb{H})$ complexifies to $\mathfrak{sl}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$.

The algebras $\mathfrak{sp}_{2p,2q}$ for $p+q=n$, $\frak{sp}_{2n}$, and $\frak{sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ complexify to $\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$.

The algebras $\mathfrak{so}_{p,q}$ for $p+q=n$  corresponds to $\mathfrak{so_{n}}(\mathbb{C})$, with the additional rule that $\mathfrak{so}_n(\mathbb{H})$ corresponds to $\mathfrak{so}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$

Lastly we get to the exotic cases. First, $\frak{g_2}$ has two algebras that complexify to it, $\frak{g}_2^{-14}$ and $\frak{g}_2^2$. The first of these is the lie algebra of the group of algebra-automorpism of the Octonions, $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{O})$. The second of these can be described as the lie algebra of the group of embeddings of $\mathbb{H}$ into $\mathbb{O}$.

$f_4$ has three algebras that complexify to it, $\mathfrak{f_4^{-52}}$, $\mathfrak{f_4^4}$ and $\mathfrak{f_4^{-20}}$. I don't know any good descriptions of these.

There are again multiple Lie groups corresponding to each of these Lie algebras, but listing them would be extremely extensive. In addition, semi-simple Lie groups are not always products of simple lie groups, which further complicates matters.